# Ansible. Correct way to copy nginx config

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

We have task like:

```
- template: 
    src=templates/nginx/default 
    dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
    owner=root 
    group=root
```

When I run it like:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/amazon site.yml -u ubuntu --become --limit=web
```

it works. But `become` makes user act as root, and if nginx update is only part of deployment process - `become` flag is dangerous.

If we remove it - ansible gives error like:

```
TASK [nginx : template] ********************************************************
fatal: [*****.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "gid": 1000, "group": "ubuntu", "mode": "0777", "msg": "chown failed", "owner": "ubuntu", "path": "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default", "size": 275, "state": "file", "uid": 1000}
```

So.. What is correct way to update nginx config, using ansible? Can it be done without `--become`?

Comment: `become` is not dangerous. `0777` is dangerous!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, ok, removed this part :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, problem is that `become` will make **everything** in playbook under root. It's dangerous.

Comment: Why is that dangerous? Most everything you would run needs to be root.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I don't want to run my applications under root. Really. It sounds weird? Running them under simple user is fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I have 10 roles. One of them is nginx. We have to keep it commented, because it fails under ubuntu user. Other roles work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `become: yes` on the task that needs root. See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html for the official reference.